# d3 line chart with Voronoi

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to utilise the following code in my own work;

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8033015

I have it almost working, but the mouse overs code does not behave in the same way as on the sample code.

I ensure that the line is inserted into the underlying data ;

`svg.selectAll('.line')
                            .data(data)
                            .enter()
                            .append("path")
                            .attr("class", "line")
                            .attr('stroke', function(d,i){return colors[i%colors.length];})
                            .attr("d", function(d) {
                            **    d.line = this; **
                             return line(d.values)});`

I then generate the voroni data as per the sample code;

```
 var vr = (voronoi(d3.nest()
               .key(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp) + "," + y(d.attainment) + y(d.dcuid); })
               .rollup(function(v) { return v[0]; })
               .entries(d3.merge(data.map(function(d) { return d.values; })))
               .map(function(d) { return d.values; })));
```

But my problem comes when I want to look at that augmented data in the voronoi mouse over - the line object is no longer there.

```
voronoiGroup.selectAll(".line")
 .data(vr)
 .enter().append("path")
 .attr("d", function(d) {return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";})
 .datum(function(d) {return d.point; })
 .on("mouseover", function(d){alert(d.line)})
```

In the demo code, the alert would work.

I have put together a fiddle of my issue here;

http://jsfiddle.net/CCpPQ/2/